# vim: how to add line break where cursor is and paste a line after the new linebreak with one paste operation

Tags: vim, copy-paste

In vim, if I've copied a line using 'yy', then 'p' will paste the copied text on a line below the cursor, and 'P' will paste the copied text to the line above the cursor... But how do I break the line where the cursor is AND paste the text there?

let's say I have this (the pipe char represents the cursor, not a character in the buffer):

```
ab|cd
```

I want a paste operation that will end me with:

```
ab
--Pasted Line--
cd
```

Basically, the end result would be the same as hitting "i<Enter>ESC" and then "P".

I actually just did this in vim accidentally, with one paste operation (without using i<Enter>ESC etc), but I'm not sure how I did it.

I know this question is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346737/how-to-paste-in-a-new-line-with-vim but it's different because I want to paste something copied using 'yy' and I also want to break the line at the point of the cursor, and paste the line where the new line break was just created.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do that: move the cursor to the insertion point and type

```
vP
```

That pastes in visual mode.  See

```
:help v_P
```

for more.

Comment: Close, but vP deletes the single character that is highlighted once the editor is in visual mode. Maybe (probably?) this is what I accidentally did, but it's not exactly what I want.

Comment: Vim's registers can be tagged as linewise or characterwise. It seemed that maybe you wanted to yank linewise but paste characterwise. I was searching for a way to do that when I found `vP`. You could also try yanking with `0y$` which would yank the line characterwise, then paste it with `p` or `P`, but that doesn't seem like exactly what you want, either.